# Finding the average of a string while going backwards

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, average

I need to define a function which receives a string (possibly containing digits, letters and/or special symbols) and returns one float number containing the average calculated considering all the digits in the string starting from the last position in the string and considering all digits (going backwards) until one letter is found or until reaching  the start of the string (and include the first character in the string for the calculation if it is a digit) . If there are no digits in the string, or if a letter is found before the first digit is found, then the function should return the value 0.0.

For example, avgBackw("-1---2--A--3--4--") should return 3.5 because the average of 4 and 3 is 3.5.

```
As an example, the following code fragment:

value = avgBackw("-1---2--A--3--4--")
print(value)

should produce the output:

3.5
```

This is the farthest I've gotten so far.. I have no idea where to go from here..

```
def avgBackw(lst): 
  rv = []  
  for n in lst[::-1]: 
    try:
        rv.append(int(lst))
    except:
        return len(rv)
return len(rv)
```

Comment: So if you want to get the average you need to keep track of a sum and the number of digits you've encountered. You can use `.isdigit()` and `.isalpha()` to check if a character is a digit or a letter. When you encounter a digit, you record its value in the sum, and when you encounter a letter, you break out of the loop. Once you're out of the loop you then return the average, which you can calculate using your sum and the number of digits. Make sure to consider the case where there are no numbers, otherwise you will be dividing by zero.

Comment: What is the purpose for finding the average backward, are special cases such as avgBackw("-1---2--A--3--04--") suppose to produce (40+3)/2 = 21.5 or just 3.5

Comment: What about when we have consecutive digits such as --A-1--45--4

Answer (score 0):

use `isalpha()` and `isdigit()`

```
def avgBack(string):
    sum, count =  0.0, 0
    for s in string[::-1]:
        if s.isalpha():
            break
        if s.isdigit():
            sum += int(s)
            count+=1
    return float(sum/count) if count else 0
```

Comment: I don't see the purpose of `float(sum/count)` -- I would have expected something like: `sum / float(count)` assuming you're trying for Python 2 and Python 3 compatibility.

Comment: This solution assumes there must be a letter terminator, so if there isn't one, e.g. `-5---4--3--2--1--`, it returns zero instead of the average.  An easy fix.

Comment: @cdlane Thanks for the suggestion, I have updated my solution.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

**1.** strip all characters except numbers and letters

**2.** reverse the stripped list

**3.** check for base cases

**4.** compute average of all numbers before a character is found

Here what a brute force approach looks like(without helpful library functions):

```
def average_back(string):
    # sum count for average
    count = 0
    sums = 0.0

    # strip the string except for the digits and letters
    stripped = []
    for char in string:
        if char.isdigit() or char.isalpha():
            stripped.append(char)

    # reverse the string
    reverse = stripped[::-1]

    # if list is empty, of no digits are found, or the first letter is a letter
    if not reverse or not has_number(reverse) or reverse[0].isalpha():
        return sums

    # loop until character is found
    for char in reverse:
        if char.isalpha():
            break
        else:
            sums += float(char)
            count += 1

    # return average
    return sums / count

def has_number(string):
    for char in string:
        if (char.isdigit()):
            return True

    return False
```

Another more concise(can be improved) implementation using higher order functions such as [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map), [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any), [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) and [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join):

```
from itertools import takewhile

def average_back2(string):

    # strip the string except for the digits and letters
    stripped = "".join(x for x in string if x.isalpha() or x.isdigit())

    # reverse the string
    reverse = stripped[::-1]

    # if list is empty, of no digits are found, or the first letter is a letter
    if not reverse or not any(x.isdigit() for x in reverse) or reverse[0].isalpha():
        return 0.0

    # concatenate numbers until non-digit is found
    valid_numbers = "".join(takewhile(lambda x : not x.isalpha(), reverse))

    # convert string to list of integers
    numbers = list(map(int, valid_numbers))

    # return sum
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Which works as follows:

```
>>> average_back("-1---2--A--3--4--")
3.5
>>> average_back2("-1---2--A--3--4--")
3.5
>>> average_back("-1---2--A--3--A--")
0.0
>>> average_back2("-1---2--A--3--A--")
0.0
>>> average_back("-A---A--A--A--1--")
1.0
>>> average_back2("-A---A--A--A--1--")
1.0
>>> average_back("-A---A--A--A--A--")
0.0
>>> average_back2("-A---A--A--A--A--")
0.0
>>> average_back("-5---4--3--2--1--")
3.0
>>> average_back2("-5---4--3--2--1--")
3.0
>>> average_back("-A---4--3--2--1--")
2.5
>>> average_back2("-A---4--3--2--1--")
2.5
>>> average_back("-A---4--A--2--1--")
1.5
>>> average_back2("-A---4--A--2--1--")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to solve your question like this example: (See the comments to understand what's going under the hood):

```
import re 

def find_sep(a):
    '''Find the separator which is anything except numbers and "-" '''
    # é, è, æ, etc ... are not a valid separators.
    # Otherwise, add them to the next line in the regex rule
    sep = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]', a[::-1])
    if sep:
        # Reverse the string
        # And take the first part of the string if we find a separator
        return a[::-1].split(sep[0])[0]
    else:
        # Return the string reversed
        return a[::-1]


def average_backwards(a):
    '''Reverse the string and calculate the average'''
    # Find the seperator if exists and return an inversed string with numbers if they exists
    b = find_sep(a)
    # Find all the numbers
    nums = re.findall(r'(\d+)', b[::-1])
    if nums:
        avg = round(sum(map(int, nums))/len(nums), 2)
        return avg
    return 0.0


# Test

nums = ["-1---2--b--3--04--", "-1---2--e--3--4--", "-1---2--A--3--A--", "-1---2--A--3----", 
        "-A---A--A--A--1--", "-A---A--A--+--1--", "-A---A--A--A--A--", "-A---2--A--A--A--", 
        "-5---4--3--2--1--", "-5-Z--4--3--2--1--", "-A---4--3------", "-A---4--c--2--1--", 
        "----4--A--2--1--", "-A---4--A--2--1--", "-5-Z--4-+3--2--1-"]


for num in nums:
    print('{0} -> avg: {1}'.format(num, average_backwards(num)))
```

Output:

```
-1---2--b--3--04-- => 3.5
-1---2--e--3--4-- => 3.5
-1---2--A--3--A-- => 0.0
-1---2--A--3---- => 3.0
-A---A--A--A--1-- => 1.0
-A---A--A--+--1-- => 1.0
-A---A--A--A--A-- => 0.0
-A---2--A--A--A-- => 0.0
-5---4--3--2--1-- => 3.0
-5-Z--4--3--2--1-- => 2.5
-A---4--3------ => 3.5
-A---4--c--2--1-- => 1.5
----4--A--2--1-- => 1.5
-A---4--A--2--1-- => 1.5
-5-Z--4-+3--2--1- => 2.5
```

Comment: Can you explain `-A---4--c--2--1-- -> avg: 2.33` given the OP's description of the problem?  I don't see how it differs from `-A---4--A--2--1-- -> avg: 1.5`.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @cdlane for pointing this error. I just have to reverse `a` in `find_sep`. See the last edit. The idea behind is to find the first letter in the reversed string, then split the string by this letter then find all the numbers, sum them and find their average.

Comment: The OP was clear that a letter (or end of string) stops the processing but your code stops on other punctuation, e.g. `-5-Z--4-+3--2--1- -> avg: 2.0`

Comment: I see. So, i need to modify the regex under find_sep. I'm updating my answer. Thanks @cdlane

Answer (score 0):

I never miss an opportunity to throw itertools.groupby at a problem:

```
from itertools import groupby

def avgBackw(string):
    digits = list()

    for key, group in groupby(string[::-1], lambda c: c.isalnum() + c.isdigit()):

        if key == 1:  # we hit one or more letters
            break

        if key == 2: # we hit one or more digits
            digits += group

    return sum(map(int, digits)) / len(digits) if digits else 0
```